# Air on ios using Staring found error:#3768

Tags: air, starling-framework

When i run the app on device and press home or view the notification, the air app run in background, and the show the error:3768
I was using air sdk 3.9, starling 1.2, running on ios7
This problem fix while using air sdk 3.8, or on desktop.
But the app seems runs perfect.
I guess the deactived event did not dispatch right after the app run into background.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in air sdk 3.9 : https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3630105.
Else if you use Starling 1.5, this problem will fix.

You can find more details here : http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/problem-with-adobe-air-sdk-39.